# getting error in react: Line 25: 'totalIncome' is not defined no-undef

Tags: html, reactjs, components, jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class CalculateIncome extends Component {
        state = {
            totalIncome:0
        }

        calculation = () => {
            this.props.lessons.filter(lesson => {
                this.props.clients.filter(client => {
                    if (client.name === lesson.name){
                        let income = client.price * lesson.time;
                        let totalIncome = this.state.totalIncome + income
                        return(
                            totalIncome
                        )
                    }
                    return (
                        this.setState({
                            totalIncome : totalIncome   //this is the error
                        })
                    )
                })      
                return (this.state.totalIncome)
            })
        }

        render() {
            console.log(this.props.lessons, this.props.clients) //this checks out!
            return ( this.props.lessons.length ? 
            (
                <div onLoad={this.calculation}>{this.state.totalIncome}</div>
            )  
                : 
            (<div className="text-center my-5">You are broke</div>) 
        )
    }
}

export default CalculateIncome
```

The props from App.js are loading in correctly because I can see them showing up when I do console.log();

The overall purpose of this calculation is to take the added new lesson and run it through the list of existing clients and multiply the time or duration of the lesson with the price that is listed with the client so I can get my income. Then I want to add that individual income to the total income and display it.

I am either getting an undefined error or if I move things around I get a "needs a return value" error. I am new at react so I am very confused. Any help would be appreciated, thanks! If you need more of my components, please let me know.

Comment: move your calculation() to componentDidMount(), see react lifecycle methods.(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) 

What you have to do is
1. get props from app.js
2. perform calcuation (CdM())
3. render based on calculation

Error is : 
You have return this.setState(xyz). But the method does not return anything.

Comment: i dont understand what you want todo with "this.props.clients.filter", maybe you should to use a reduce to return only one value. anyway, i think your "totalIncome" in setState on calculator is not define.

Comment: @EdisonJunior My thought process was filtering through each lesson and for each lesson filter through the list of existing clients until I find the one that matches the same name. There I would do the math and then send the answer back and add it to totalIncome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to be using state for this calculation at all (if you did it the way you're trying, your component will re-render for every client-lesson match. Here's a quick (untested) way you could do it.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

class CalculateIncome extends PureComponent {
        calculation = () => {
            const { lessons = [], clients = [] } = this.props;
            let totalIncome = 0;
            lessons.forEach(lesson => {
                clients.forEach(client => {
                    if (client.name === lesson.name) {
                        totalIncome += client.price * lesson.time;
                    }
                });
            });
            return totalIncome;
        }

        render() {
            const { lessons } = this.props;

            if (lessons.length) {
                const totalIncome = this.calculation();
                return <div>{totalIncome}</div>;
            }
            return <div className="text-center my-5">You are broke</div>;
        )
    }
}

export default CalculateIncome;
```

Comment: oh jeez, this worked, thank you so much! I had been stuck on this for two days.